# How to configure the hive.Connection() to pass Hive the settings I want?

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, spyder, pyhive

I am running Spyder 3.2.8 on Ubuntu 17.10.
I would like to pass Hive that is on remote cluster to give names to column names using the `set hive.cli.print.header=true;` command.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
con = hive.Connection(host="name", 
                      port=some port, 
                      username="usr",
                      configuration='hive.cli.print.header = True')
```

What is the right way to set configuration, I can't find even one working example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

conn = hive.Connection(host="host", port="port", username="user",password="passwd",auth='LDAP',configuration={'hive.auto.convert.join':'false','mapred.mappers.tasks':'25','mapred.job.shuffle.input.buffer.percent':'0.50','mapreduce.map.memory.mb':'12000','mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb':'12000','mapred.reduce.child.java.opts':'-Xmx12000m','mapred.map.child.java.opts':'-Xmx12000m','hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer':'104857600','hive.optimize.skewjoin':'true'})